# how to selectively use annotation while in custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger, spring-annotations

```
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ResourceErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 424, message = "Failed Dependency", response = ResourceErrorModel.class)})
public @interface DefaultAPIResponse{}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. If we replace with @DefaultAPIResponse, it replaces with al the annotations that are defined under it but what if we want to use it as per our need like if we want to exclude @ApiResponse(code = 422 and 424).
Is there any way to use selective api response annotations in custom annotation as per choice. If then how to implement?

Comment: Requesting all, if any one can look into this problem would be gateful